# ScrollIntoView to a part of the page of a Lightning Tree structure in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

Is it possible to automatically scrollIntoView to the part of the page where a specific node is expanded programatically in a Role hierarchy created using a Lightning-Tree component. The hierarchy is pretty big. A sample [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/18eVY3CN/17/edit).

For example

## treesample.html

```
<template> 
     <lightning-tree items={items} selected-item={selectedUserRole} header="Roles"></lightning-tree>
</template>
```

## treesample.js

```
  import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TreeBasic extends LightningElement {

 selectedUserRole = 'CA Sales Rep';

 items = [
    {
        label: 'Western Sales Director',
        name: 'Western Sales Director',
        expanded: true,
        items: [
            {
                label: 'Western Sales Manager',
                name: 'Western Sales Manager',
                expanded: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'CA Sales Rep',
                        name: 'CA Sales Rep',
                        expanded: true,
                        items: [],
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'OR Sales Rep',
                        name: 'OR Sales Rep',
                        expanded: true,
                        items: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }

   ];



     renderedCallback(){
         // scrollIntoView to the Role 'CA Sales Rep'
       }
  }
```

Edit:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? Read about the [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to see if it applies to you.

Comment: Trying to see if I can scrollIntoView to a specific Role (as per the selected User) once the page is rendered

Comment: Modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly you want to take the user to a particular node programmatically.

`<lightning-tree>` use an anchor tag `<a>` to present a node and a `<span>` to render the title. focusing on  element is an all-time challenge. We can call .foucus on a `<div>` but can not do the same for `<span>`

The closest solution will be closing all the nodes except the one you want to navigate. below is the way to programmatically accessing a node and closing/expanding it. You need to iterate through all the node and when you find your match you expand it or else close it.

```
let allItems = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree');
    for(let index= 0; index < allItems.items.length ; index++){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(allItems.items[index]));
        // Please change your logic. this is an working example
        if(index % 2 === 0){
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree').items[index].expanded = false;
        }
        else{
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree').items[index].expanded = true;
        }
    }
```

see a working example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/18eVY3CN/11/edit)

Comment: Tried but since there is only one 'lightning-tree', its length returns as 1. I also tried "this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-item') " as it represents each node but returned as null.

Comment: Added a snapshot

Comment: But it only works on the first level of the tree.  Anyway got it working using the 'selected-item' attribute in lightning-tree to open the required node. However I need to scrolldown to the part of the page where the node just got opened. have a deeply nested tree structure that goes well beyond one page. Closing all other nodes doesn't help either. Can you check this sample   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/18eVY3CN/15/edit